# Javascript placing table rows between rows with greater and smaller ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm building a system which outputs a list of cars on a screen(in a table element). The page loads the updates automatically with an HTTP call to the server.

Every car has an ID, a status and some irrelevant things.
Now when the user loads the page, the cars without the statuses 'maintenance' and 'wrecked'  are shown and every five seconds new JSON data will be loaded from the server. If there comes a car out of the maintenance this one should be added to the table. The table is sorted by the car id and here comes the problem.
I have written a bit of pseudo code to clarify my problem:

```
if (row_with_greater_id_exits && row_with_lower_id_exists) {
    place_row_between_firstRowWithGreaterId_and_FirstRowWithLowerId();
} else if (is_row_with_greater_id) {
    jQuery('table#cars tbody').append(generatedHtml);
} else if (is_row_with_lower_id) {
    jQuery('table#cars tbody').prepend(generatedHtml);
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to find the first row with a greater id or the first row with a smaller ID. The ID's are not always succeeding because some cars are wrecked and have the status wrecked.

I hope someone here has had a similar problem and can help me on my way to the solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do the ID's normally look like when produced? i.e. id="car-1" etc.

Comment: I have this: id="car-1" data-id="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have this:* `id="car-1" data-id="1"`

I'll assume that `data` attribute is on the `tr` elements. Obviously you can adapt the following if it is on a cell within a row.

Loop through the table checking each row's id, and insert the new row immediately before the first row that has an id greater than the new one:

```
// assume newId is the new ID, somehow set from your JSON

var rowInserted = false;
jQuery('#invoices-outstanding tbody tr').each(function() {
   var $row = $(this);
   if (+$row.attr("data-id") > newId) {
      $row.before(generatedHtml);
      rowInserted = true;
      // break out of each loop
      return false;
   }
});
if (!rowInserted)
   jQuery('#invoices-outstanding tbody').append(generatedHtml);
```

Comment: Implemented this code but after the update the new rows with ID's which should be placed between two rows are placed at the top of the table.. No errors in firebug console..

Comment: Are you saying the highest ids are _first_ in your table? My code assumes the lowest ids are first, so you'd have to change the `>` to a `<`. I mentioned a couple of assumptions in my answer - did you allow for those in your code? Without seeing your html or how you've processed your JSON response I really can't tell what's going wrong. I suggest updating your question to show the code you have (please don't just post it in a comment).

Comment: Will test my code now and see if it works properly, will be back in one minute.

Comment: This seems to work good! Thank you! Will accept after finishing conversation with the system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the rows, and compare the ids. When your new row has and ID less than the current row in the loop, insert the new row before the current row, and break the loop.

```
rows.each(function(i, el) {
    if (+newrow.id < +el.id) {
        $(el).before(newrow);
        return false;
    }
})
if (!newrow.parentNode)
    rows.parent().append(newrow);
```

This code assumes `rows` is a jQuery object that has a collection of all the rows, and `newrow` is a DOM element representing the new row.

Also assumes that the IDs are simple numbers. Note that numeric IDs are only valid in HTML5.

---

Personally, I'd just use the native API for this:

```
var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

tbody.insertBefore(newrow, [].reduce.call(tbody.rows, function(bef, el) {
    return bef || +newrow.id > +el.id ? bef : el;
}, null));
```

No need to test for the `isFirstLoad`. When the `tbody` is empty, it'll still work. But you'll need a `.reduce()` shim for older browsers.

Comment: You had left out the `return false`

Comment: Just edited to this: if (isFirstLoad) {   
    jQuery('table#cars tbody').append(car);
} else {
    var rows = jQuery('table#cars tr');
    rows.each(function (i, el) {
        if (+key < +el.id) {
            $(el).before(car);
            return false
        }
    });
    
    if (!car.parentNode)
        rows.parent().append(car);
}, now the new cars are added to the top of the table, while they should be placed in between the two rows..

Comment: Is `car` a `<tr>` element? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: Yes it is. tr in tbody in table

Comment: It needs to be a DOM element. If it's a jQuery object, then you need to use `.prop("id")` to get the ID, and `.parent()` instead of `.parentNode` to get the parent.

Comment: Your code shows the following error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLTableSectionElement.insertBefore]
}, null)); What's going wrong? I had to edit the querySelector, because there are more tables on that page. document.querySelector("table#cars tbody");

Comment: Again, is `car` a jQuery object? If so, you need to either use jQuery, or you need to extract the DOM element from it, like `car[0]`.

Comment: Sorry, car is a jQuery object. I dit this now: car.prop('id'); but i still get the eroror with NS_ERROR_XPC_....

Comment: I don't know which example you're testing... the first or the second. If you're testing the second, then you need to get rid of the jQuery object altogether.

Comment: I prefer not to get rid of the jQuery object, so I'll try the first example aswell. Can I accept two answers with stackoverflow? If not, how can I give credit to both of you guys?

Comment: Go ahead and accept the other one. For some reason that one got a downvote.

Comment: You can upvote as many answers as you like, and then accept whichever one helped the most. @thesystem - Sorry that my answer ended up similar to yours: I had typed most of it before I saw yours, and I decided to go ahead and post mine anyway because I'd used the identifiers mentioned in the question and thought that might help the OP get it done faster.

Comment: @nnnnnn: No problem at all. :)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly I did not manage to get your first code example working as well, I think that also happens because of me using jQuery.... Nevertheless, thanks for your time!